# Configuring NetGear router with PHP Front End?

Tags: webserver, lamp, router

I have a netgear router and a PC that functions as the server. On the server I have a website that is hosted on a WAMP solution (windows, apache, mysql, php). Linux is an option, but Windows is first prize in this specific scenario.

What I need:

1. If someone connects to the wireless network, the splash page that is hosted on the server must be displayed.
2. All users must have bandwidth limits that are configurable for each user
3. I must be able to interact with the router via PHP code, in order to execute certain functions when certain users logon, etc.

So, my question is, how do people normally do this? Is there a way to configure this on the router (users connect to ROUTER), or is this something that can only be accomplished with a PROXY (users connect to proxy on server, server connects to internet via router).

Is this possible? Is there software available that does this? Is a proxy what I really need?

Comment: Why can't you setup a page that checks how much bandwidth was used and then block or allow access?  Just install a logs program on the server and query the logs.

Comment: I am stuck at the part where it automatically shows an Apache page if you connect to the network the first time?

Comment: There is some interesting things in want you want to set up. But as a suggestion I recommend you to break your question in smaller chunks.

Answer (score 0):

[If your router supports it](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database), you can install [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com) onto the router and use [NoCatSplash](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/NoCatSplash) to capture the connected user's first HTTP request and redirect it as needed.